# c# async и новый объект

Tags: c#, асинхронность

У менять есть XML файл, который загружаю асинхронно, после чего с помощью этого файла я инициализирую новый объект, но уже не асинхронно. Стоит ли инициализацию также проводить асинхронно? Или код корректно отработает, если, предположим, там будет много данных? Если нужно асинхронно, то не подскажите паттерн, пока что нашел [с помощью Task.Delay подождать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-services), но это как-то рандомно?

```
protected async Task<bool> TryLoad(GameDataBase gamedata)
{
    XmlHandle handle = new XmlHandle();
    bool result = await handle.TryLoad(PathFile);

    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = gamedata.Load(handle);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Task.Delay` там просто для примера, что работа сервиса занимает время. Почему не сделать метод `gameData.Load` асинхронным?

Comment: Да было бы там что-то асинхронное... Там просто поля класса заполняются.

Comment: Раз там просто заполняются поля, то нужно оставить как есть, даже если там будет очень много полей и таких объектов будет 1000.

Comment: Вообще смысла в асинхронности здесь нет, но если очень хочется, то вот решение: `result = await Task.Run(() => gamedata.Load(handle));` это стандартный способ запустить асинхронно [CPU-Bound операцию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async#cpu-bound-example-perform-a-calculation-for-a-game).

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронными стоит делать методы, в которых возможно некое ожидание:

- Ввода-вывода
- Чтения-записи в файл/БД
- Получения данных из сети

И т.д.

В вашем случае нет смысла делать инициализацию асинхронной, если у вас нет никакого ожидания, а просто линейный код.

Comment: А как же CPU-Bound? Может есть смысл дополнить ответ?

Comment: @aepot cpu-bound задачи ведь решаются многопоточностью, хотя её и можно обернуть в асинхронность, если так удобнее в конкретном случае )